# Rails ancestry with nil parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I'm building a hierarchical category in Rails using Ancestry, and I allow the user to choose the parent of the object they're creating.  I display the existing categories using a dropdown:

```
<%= f.input :ancestry, collection: Category.sorted_list %>
```

As long as the user chooses an existing node, all is well.  If the user chooses the blank in the dropdown, I would expect Ancestry to create a root node, but instead the form throws an "is invalid" error.

My controller isn't doing anything mindblowing:

```
def update
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])        
      format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }        
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else        
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end     
  end 
end
```

I'm newer to Rails, so I'm not sure how to attack this problem.  Is there a configuration for Ancestry that I missed, or is this a form validator being over-protective perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That happens because `ancestry` can't be `nil` and it's a bad idea to change it manually because all the gem's behavior is based on this attribute. For such cases gem has another `parent_id` attribute which you should use in your form.

There is a good explanation in [gem's wiki](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/wiki/Creating-a-selectbox-for-a-form-using-ancestry) how to build form using `ancestry`

Hope it helps

Comment: So maybe I just don't understand how to set up a Category model correctly, then.  If I add a :parent_id select to my form, I get a "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: parent_id" error from the controller.  

Do I need to have both an ancestry AND a parent_id column?

Comment: You dont need to have `parent_id` in your database, just `ancestry` column. But you have to put `parent_id` to `attr_accessible` to avoid mass-assignment error

Answer (score 1):

Ancestry validates his field with [this](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/blob/7a5e0910f22eabe66bcd59d09dea2c59815dd00f/lib/ancestry/has_ancestry.rb#L34):

```
# Validate format of ancestry column value
validates_format_of ancestry_column, :with => Ancestry::ANCESTRY_PATTERN, :allow_nil => true
```

But you can't pass `nil` value in forms. So I did this:

```
before_validation do
  self.ancestry = nil if self.ancestry.blank?
end
```